# How can I make my python script write to a different set of columns xcel after matching in regex/seperating/lists etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, openpyxl

This is my second thing I've ever made in python or any other code, so my code probably sucks completely, but the function of my script is supposed to be:

1. Input a destination to save an xcel file
2. Input a name of a workbook in the excel file
3. Create columns/headers in xcel with table searching functionality
4. Input a file to digest
5. find specific data in the file and write in the rows of specific columns using regex
6. See if another workbook needs to be created

```
import os
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import openpyxl.worksheet.filters 
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
import random

nums = list(range(1, 100000)) 
resultSet=set(nums)
uniqueList =list(resultSet)
repeat = '1'
wb = Workbook()
path2 = input("Please input the path of where you want to save the file:\n")
while repeat == '1':
    s1 = input("Please input the title of the worksheet:\n")
    regex1 = r'Internet.*' #For "show ip arp":
    regex2 = r'^(?=(Gi\d)|(Te\d)|(Fa\d)|(Po\d)|(Twe\d)|(Hu\d)).*' #For "show interface status"
    regex3 = r'^(?=(\s{1,3}\d{1,4})|(\sAll)).*\w{4}\..*' #For "show mac add | exc ffff.ffff.ffff|0100.5e"
    path_input = (input("Please input the path of the file you want to digest:\n"))
    aflac = random.sample(uniqueList, 1)
    t1 = aflac
    aflac = random.sample(uniqueList, 1)
    t2 = aflac
    aflac = random.sample(uniqueList, 1)
    t3 = aflac
    aflac = random.sample(uniqueList, 1)
    wb.create_sheet(s1)
    ws = wb[s1]
    style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleLight13", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
    ws['A1'].value = "Port"
    ws['B1'].value = "Name"
    ws['C1'].value = "Status"
    ws['D1'].value = "Vlan"
    ws['E1'].value = "Duplex"
    ws['F1'].value = "Speed"
    ws['G1'].value = "Type"
    ws['H1'].value = "IP Address"
    ws['I1'].value = "Mac Address"
    ws['J1'].value = "Notes"
    ws['K1'].value = "Sort"
    tab1 = Table(displayName=str(t1), ref="A1:K900")
    tab1.tableStyleInfo = style
    ws.add_table(tab1)
    ws['O1'].value = "Protocol"
    ws['P1'].value = "Address"
    ws['Q1'].value = "Age"
    ws['R1'].value = "Hardware Address"
    ws['S1'].value = "Type"
    ws['T1'].value = "Interface"
    tab2 = Table(displayName=str(t2), ref="O1:T900")
    tab2.tableStyleInfo = style
    ws.add_table(tab2)
    ws['V1'].value = "Vlan"
    ws['W1'].value = "Mac Address"
    ws['X1'].value = "Type"
    ws['Y1'].value = "Ports"
    tab3 = Table(displayName=str(t3), ref="V1:Y900")
    tab3.tableStyleInfo = style
    ws.add_table(tab3)
    f1 = (os.path.expanduser(path_input))
    g1 = open(f1, 'r')
    strings = re.findall(regex1, g1.read())
    writing = '\n'.join(map(str, strings))
    list = (writing.split())
    lisbon = 15
    cascais = 2
    for index, value in enumerate(list):
        ws.cell(row=index+cascais, column=lisbon, value=value)
        lisbon = lisbon + 1
        lisbon
        cascais = cascais - 1
        cascais
        if lisbon == 21:
            lisbon = lisbon - 6
            cascais = cascais + 1
    g1.close()
    g1 = 0
    f1 = 0
    list = 0
    writing = 0
    value = 0
    row = 0
    column = 0
    f1 = (os.path.expanduser(path_input))
    g1 = open(f1, 'r')
    strings = re.findall(regex2, g1.read())
    writing = '\n'.join(map(str, strings))
    list = (writing.split())
    Atlanta = 1  #For Regex 2
    Porto = 2  #For Regex 2
    for index, value in enumerate(list):
        ws.cell(row=index+Porto, column=Atlanta, value=value)
        Atlanta = Atlanta + 1
        Atlanta
        Porto = Porto - 1
        Porto
        if Atlanta == 12:
            Atlanta = Atlanta - 11
            Porto = Porto + 1

    repeat = input("To create another workbook enter 1 to finish creating workbook enter 0:\n")

wb.save(path2)
```

This script works when I am writing to the first set of columns I need using the first regex and loop:

```
    for index, value in enumerate(list):
        ws.cell(row=index+cascais, column=lisbon, value=value)
        lisbon = lisbon + 1
        lisbon
        cascais = cascais - 1
        cascais
        if lisbon == 21:
            lisbon = lisbon - 6
            cascais = cascais + 1
```

However, when the second regex is used, it is still writing to the first column set above instead of the second column set:

```
    Atlanta = 1  #For Regex 2
    Porto = 2  #For Regex 2
    for index, value in enumerate(list):
        ws.cell(row=index+Porto, column=Atlanta, value=value)
        Atlanta = Atlanta + 1
        Atlanta
        Porto = Porto - 1
        Porto
        if Atlanta == 12:
            Atlanta = Atlanta - 11
            Porto = Porto + 1
```

Regex does not appear to be the issue, but the first for loop in the ws.cell as it is continueing to write to the same columns with the second regex.

My question is, how can I write to the second set of columns with the second regex?

Data in the file being digested:

```html
Device#show ip arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  1.1.1.1              -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1                -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1              165   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1              165   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1                0   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1               -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1              70   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1               -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1             81   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1                -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.1                1   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan1
Device#show mac address-table 
Unicast Entries
 vlan     mac address     type        protocols               port
---------+---------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------------
   1      0000.0000.0001    static ip,ipx,assigned,other Switch                     
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1        
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1              
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1        
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1        
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1        
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1        
   1      0000.0000.0001   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Vlan1   
Device#show int status
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/1     comments connected    1         full   1000 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/2     comments connected    1         full   1000 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/3     comments connected    1         full   1000 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/4     comments connected    1         full    100 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/5     comments connected    1         full   auto 10/100/1000-TX
```

I've tried using different variables for the second regex, closing the file and reopening, changing the variables to 0 after running the first ws.cell column for loop and have 31 different save files trying different things to try and get this working.

I hate asking for help, but I am out of ideas. If someone has a way to fix this I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).